# Configure log4j - nothing works

Tags: java, log4j

This is the resources/log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

these are the depdendencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and this is the code:

```
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class.getName());
        logger.info("hahahaha");
```

Why it doesn't work? It shoud print logs to the console output is only:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please give the logs (console output).

Comment: You are using Log4j 2 (version is 2.x) - so that expects a properties file called `log4j2.properties`. I typically use an XML file instead - `log4j2.xml` - see examples [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: ye, now it works, thank you.